Partition Selection for Event Hubs with Mixed Kafka and Native Event Hub Producer Clients
I'm using Event Hubs to broker events published from a system using the native Event Hubs C# client. In addition, I'm using the Kafka client in Databricks to publish events to the same hub. The ordering is important, so I leverage the partition key to ensure the co-location of related events.
However, I've noticed that the calculated partition of the key is different between clients. My understanding is that Event Hubs partitioning by key is calculated inside the hub and is abstracted away from the client. The Kafka client appears to use MurmurHash to calculate the partitioning inside the client. So the results for the same key differ across processes.
Is there a way to have the Kafka client defer the partitioning to Event Hubs in order to get the same outcome as the native Event Hubs interface?

Partitions are always computed / provided client-side, as per the Kafka network protocol.
The Confluent dotnet client is based on librdkafka, which does not default to murmur2 hash. It uses CRC32. Look at the partitioner config - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/html/md_CONFIGURATION.html

Are you suggesting that a possible solution is to use the Kafka API with dotnet client instead of the native Event Hubs client? And then synchronise the partitioning algorithm?

That should be possible. E.g C# isn't a requirement to use EventHubs. You can enable the Kafka compatibility mode, and use any client

An alternative to changing your client use would be to have your application assign specific partitions and publish with direct partition assignment rather than partition keys.
